# How does garbage collection in regards to Ctx.Owner in scala.rx work?

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, scala.js, scala.rx

I am trying to wrap my head around how exactly ownerships works in [scala.rx](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx). At the moment I have a [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/) web application that just imports `rx.Ctx.Owner.Unsafe._` wherever I am using `Rx`s. This - however - leads to the creation of a lot of detached DOM elements because this unsafe global owner keeps a reference to all `Rx`s ever created and never lets them go. That way, all DOM elements that I am creating using [scalatags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags) and [scalatags-rx](https://github.com/rtimush/scalatags-rx) remain in my application as detached elements forever.

What I would like to do now is to create one `implicit val pageOwner: Ctx.Owner = Ctx.Owner.safe()` for every one of my application's pages and once navigating away from this page, I would like to somehow `kill()` all `Rx`s owned by this owner so they can be garbage collected. There is no `kill()` method defined on `Ctx.Owner`, so I have been wondering if garbage collection would work if the owner itself is garbage collected.